# Implementing Price scale on AddToCart

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I need to update product price on Product detail page based upon the quantity selected by the user.

When the user `ADD` an item to the cart, scaled price should be reflected according to the quantity they select `(qnty: "1-to-3", Price="$30", qnty: "4-to-6",Price ="$25")` and it should get reflected on `MiniCart` also.

I tried by overriding `AddCartLineBlock` pipeline (in `Sitecore.Commerce.PlugIn.Carts.dll`) to update the price, but it didn't work.

Is there any other way I could update the Cart price on `AddToCart` action and proceed to checkout flow with the updated price ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're describing is called a price card. Price cards allow you to specify discounts for quantities added to the cart, and also dates that the prices apply. You can add/modify price cards from the pricing section in biztools. I would recommend using price cards rather than implementing custom functionality.
In the Habitat environment, you can get to the price cards by going to 
`Pricing > (Price Books) Habitat_PriceBook` and you'll find the price card section there.

Comment: Hi Sandy, that information was really helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Price card is having only [currency and unit-price]. How to calculate price, if we need to calculate price by considering 1 more factor( say, unit of scale, eg. : an item or a package of 100 items). How can we achieve this ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? A discount for 100 items sounds like exactly what a price card is for. If it's a package, maybe it should have a different SKU.

Comment: For me, the product details come from an external system. Which we sync with sitecore Catalog to generate the Catalog items. Every Product have 3 properties - Currency(eg: dollar), Quantity, and UnitOfMeasure(eg: 1 item, a package containing 100 items, etc.). Price has to be calculated based upon "UnitOfMeasure" field value. Can we achieve this using Price book ya need to go with extending any pipeline ?

Comment: Maybe you mean a variant? e.g. 1 coke can individually, or a package of 24 coke cans together? Similar to t-shirt size or colour, where the product is the same but the colour/size/quantity is different. Sorry if I'm way off.